# Finding three coefficients (weight/ratio) by minimising variance

Tags: variance, covariance, lagrange-multipliers

I am finding the value of a,b and c for minimising the variance of the following equation (four variables are correlated):
$$
Var(\Delta V)=V ar[\Delta S-a\Delta F_1 - b\Delta F_2 -c\Delta F_3]
$$
where$$
a+b+c=1
$$
I know how to solve when there are only two variables. However, I wonder if there is any general formula to expand the variance equation?

This is some additional information to make this clearer:
I will leave the variance as $\sigma^2$ and similar for covariance for finding the value of a,b and c.

I used Lagrange to solve, but the answer is weird. I first expand the above variance equation to their simplest form, e.g. $\sigma_{F_1}$ and so on, and then use Lagrange to derive and the equations are long and complex.

The reason that I ask if there is a general equation/rule for expansion is that it takes 3 A4 pages to solve the problem. I got c=0 and am still finding if I did any mistakes in the steps.

Comment: Expand out the variance in terms of $Var(\Delta X)$'s and also the covariances  $Cov(\Delta X,\Delta Y)$. Then differentiate with respect to $a,b,c$ using Lagrange multiplier $a + b + c - 1 = 0$. See if that leads any where interesting.

Comment: Yes I did Lagrange and got $c=0$ and $a=\frac{Var(F_2)-Cov(F_1,F_2)}{Var(F_1)+Var(F_2)-2\rho\sigma_{F1}\sigma_{F2}}$. not sure if I did any mistakes because it takes 3 A4 pages to solve.